# Does environment.getProperty("property") produces the same value as @Value("property")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm refactoring a project and on one of the services I found this piece of code:

```
@Service
public class MyService {   
    private String API_PORT;


    public JenkinsService(final Environment environment) {
        this.API_PORT = environment.getProperty("server.port");
    }
}
```

My doubt is if I can change it to the following code (Using @Value) without unexpected behavior:

```
@Service
public class MyService {   
    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String API_PORT;


    public JenkinsService() {}
}
```

Comment: This code will likely fail, because Spring Boot won't know how to convert a `String` to `JenkinsServer`

Comment: Thanks @larsgrefer, I fixed the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment expose all properties, you generally don't want that.
Besides, it exposes also information about profiles (distinguishing which activated and all) which here you don't care.

Property placeholder `${...}` should always be favored to injecting `Environment` instance but for fair reasons as stated by the [Environment javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) (emphasis is mine) :

> **In most cases, however, application-level beans should not need to
>   interact with the Environment directly but instead may have to have
>   ${...} property values replaced by a property placeholder** configurer
>   such as PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, which itself is
>   EnvironmentAware and as of Spring 3.1 is registered by default when
>   using .

And not directly your question, but constructor injection should be favored over field injection that encourages opaque and flawed design :

```
public class MyService {   

    private final String apiPort;

    public MyService (@Value("${server.port}") String apiPort){
        this.apiPort = apiPort;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Yes

Unless you do strange things with custom `PropertyPlaceholderResover`s, the both examples will do exactly the same in a default Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

${server.port} will have an Integer value.

@Value("${server.port}")
private int API_PORT